# Is relational db frameworks like Knex really use asynchronous IO on NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I've read that relational databases management systems, RBDMS, are not a god fit for NodeJS non-blocking IO model. The main reason is that RBDMS connections and transactions are stateful.

I've been playing with NodeJS, PostgreSQL and Knex for a while. Knex allows me to write something like this:

```
      await knex.transaction(async (trx) => {
        const _id = await trx.insert(data)
                             .into('customer')
                             .returning('id');

        const customer_id = parseInt(_id[0]);

        await trx.insert({
            'customer_id': customer_id,
            'created_at' : new Date(),
            'op' : 'customer_creation'
            })
          .update({customer_id : customer_id})
          .into('customer_history');
      });
```

Do you know if Knex `await` calls are actually using real non blocking IO? Or is it using some hack under the hoods?

regards!

Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about all the RBDMS that knex supports, but as Of PostGres & MySQL are async (they implement some kind of communication protocol between your node & the DB server) therefore, it takes advantage of the async nature of Node.js.

You can check it easily, use [`asCallback`](http://knexjs.org/#Interfaces-asCallback) instead of the Promise API.

```js
knex
  .transaction(async (trx) => {
    console.log('1');
    trx
      .insert(data)
      .into('customer')
      .returning('id')
      .asCallback(function (err, rows) {
        rows;
      });
    console.log('2');
  })
  .asCallback(function (err, rows) {
    console.log('3');
  });
console.log('4');
```

And check that the first `console.log` will be `4`, that means that the task enqueued in event loop -> that means it was async.